# Fargate sceduled task FailedInvocation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I have a fargate task that I want to run as a scheduled task every *n* minutes. I have a task definition that works perfectly as expected (with cloud watch logs as expected and VPC connections working properly). That is when I run it as a task or a service. However, when I try to run it as scheduled task, it does not start. I checked the cloudwatch logs, however, there are no log entries in the log group. If I lookup the metrics page, I see a *FailedInvocations* entry under the metric name.

I understand that it is a bit tricky to schedule a task in fargate, as we have to go to cloudwatch rules, and update the scheduled task there, in order to add subnets and define a security group, as this option is not available when creating the scheduled task through my ECS cluster page.

I also have studied the documentation page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131298/how-to-debug-failed-fargate-task-initialization), and also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131298/how-to-debug-failed-fargate-task-initialization) question. But I still cannot understand why it does not work. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an issue with the web interface of AWS for scheduled tasks, as they don't let me set the **assignPublicIp** to *enabled*.

Without this, the Fargate task cannot pull images from the ECR registry. However, when I started this task using boto3 using a lambda function that gets called through cloudwatch rules, it works fine.